# What to do after shutdown(sock, SD_SEND)

Tags: sockets, file-transfer, shutdown, winsock2

I want to send several files from Server to the Client but I'm having a problem.

Server sendfile code:

```
    while ((len = fread(Buffer,1,sizeof(Buffer), fs)) > 0)
    {

        if((resultEnviar = send(ClientSocket,Buffer,len,0)) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: Failed to send file %s.\n", nombreArchivoADescargar.c_str());
            break;
        }
        sumEnviada+=resultEnviar;
    }
    fclose(fs);
```

Client receiveFile code:

```
    //shutdown(sock, SD_SEND); ???????

   do{
        recvVal = recv(sock, Buffer2, sizeof(Buffer2), 0);
        if (recvVal <= 0){
          printf("Can't read from socket");
          recvVal =0;
          fclose(fp);
          continue;
        }else{
            int off =0;
        do{        
          int write_sz = fwrite(Buffer2, 1, recvVal, fp); 
          if (write_sz < 0){
              printf("Can't write to file");
              fclose(fp);
              break;};    
          if (write_sz == 0) {cout<<endl<<"Nada que copiar"<<endl; break;}
           off += write_sz;
        }while(off<recvVal);

    bzero(Buffer2, 1024);
            contador+=off;
        }
    }while (contador<LongitudArchivo);
    cout<<endl<<"Numero de bytes recibidos: "<<contador<<endl<<endl;
printf("Ok received from client!\n");
fclose(fp);
```

If I don't use the SHUTDOWN(sock, SD_SEND) I don't receive all the expected bytes but if I use it I don't know how to send more files (how to wake up the send part of the socket).

Thanks!

Comment: May you specify the type of "Buffer2"? be careful if Buffer2 is a pointer, since sizeof(Buffer2) will return the size of the pointer (4 bytes in a 32bits arch) instead of the capacity of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what `shutdown()` has to do with it. You should receive all the bytes either way. If you want to send multiple files, you will have to send the length ahead of each one and read exactly that many following bytes from the socket into each target file.

NB If `recv()` returns zero you should close the socket and *break.* If it returns -1 you should log the errno, e.g. via `perror(),` close the socket, and break.

Comment: http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable

If I do shutdown(sock, RECV) everything "works" and I actually send the length of files.

Comment: If you shutdown for read, you will receive everything that had been already buffered locally up to that point. It can't possibly be the entire file unless the entire file (a) has already been received and buffered and (b) it all fits into your socket receive buffer. The blog you cite is of no apparent relevance except the part about the sun and moon being in alignment.